# Problem using CSS to make an arch-like curve on a design layout

Tags: css, css-transitions, user-experience

Am working on a design of a card whereby I need to make the red/maroon part bend inwards (from the black part) using css. Please assist?

**HTML Markup**

```
 <div class="container phonecard2">
 </div>

<div class="btm-right">
</div>
```

**CSS code**

```
.container.phonecard2 {
    position: relative;
    background: #000;
    margin-top: 140px;
    width: 35%;
    height: 260px;
    padding: 20px;
    -moz-border-radius:15px;
    -webkit-border-radius:15px;
    border-radius: 15px;
}

.btm-right{
    position: absolute;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right:0;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 0 0 160px 450px;
    border-color: transparent transparent #ba0c2f transparent;
}
```

**PNG image of my design after the above code**
[image: PNG image after the CSS code]

Comment: can you share the image of your desired output?

Comment: @UmerbinSiddique  I dont have the image at the moment,, but I want the upper border of the red triangle (one intersecting with the black part) to bend inwards/have a curve..

Comment: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/RdmJLJ like this?

Comment: @UmerbinSiddique No,, I want the bending edge/long border intersecting with the black part to bend inwards to form a concave shape

Comment: check the pen again

Comment: @UmerbinSiddique   It works well now,, thanks alot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div class="container phonecard2">
  <div class="btm-right"></div>
</div>
<style>
    .container.phonecard2 {
      position: relative;
      background: linear-gradient(to left, #ba0c2f 70%, #000000 30%);
      margin-top: 140px;
      width: 600px;
      height: 260px;
      padding: 20px;
      border-radius: 15px;
      overflow: hidden
    }

    .btm-right {
      position: absolute;
      background: #000;
      width: 800px;
      height: 680px;
      left: -130px;
      top: -330px;
      border-radius: 0 0 580px 0;
      transform: rotate(21deg);
    }
</style>
```